# How do i find and classify the critical points of the function?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

How can I find and classify the critical points of this function? f(x,y) = x^3 - 12x + y^3 - 3y This is what I have done so far      f'x(x,y)= 3x²-12
f'y(x,y)=3y²-3
Since the above are linear , using quadratic formula
For f'x(x,y), x=2 or x = -2 and for f'y(x,y), y=1 or y= -1             Now (2,1) and (-2,-1) are the critical points or should I Set
y = 3x²-12 and so when x=2,y=0 and x=-2 y =0 So I can say (2,0) and (-2,0) are other two critical points of f(x,y) and I will do the same for 3y²-3 to get two other critical points. Any help.

Answer (score 1):

What is linear ?

Why do you set $y = 3x^2-12$ ??

From $3x^2-12=0$ we get $x= \pm 2$ and from $3y^2-3=0$ we get $y= \pm 1.$ Thus we have four critical points:

$$(2,1),(2,-1),(-2,1),(-2,-1).$$

Comment: Thanks alot. This helps.

Comment: Use the hessian matrix of $f$